# How to reset CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST

Tags: php, rest, curl

I’m using a REST API which, among other things, uses the `DELETE` method like this:

```
DELETE /resources/whatever/items/123
```

To access this using PHP I’m using cURL like this:

```
self::$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(self::$curl, array(
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
));
```

As you can see, my cURL instance is static and will be reused for subsequent calls. This works fine when switching between “builtin” request methods. For example, in my `get()` method, I do something like this:

```
curl_setopt_array(self::$curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => self::BASE . 'whatever',
));
```

and then run `curl_exec()`. By explicitly setting the request method via `CURLOPT_HTTPGET`, a possible previous `CURLOPT_POST` will be cleared.

However, setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` (for example to `DELETE`) will override any other builtin request method. That’s fine as long as I want to `DELETE` things, but calling for example `curl_setopt(self::$curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true)` will not reset the custom method; `DELETE` will still be used.

I have tried setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `null`, `false` or the empty string, but this will only result in a HTTP request like

```
 /resources/whatever/items/123
```

i.e. with the empty string as method, followed by a space, followed by the path.

I know that I could set `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `GET` instead and do GET requests without any problems, but I wonder whether there is a possiblity to reset `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66109) in PHP, since the original [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCUSTOMREQUEST) states the following:

> Restore to the internal default by setting this to NULL.

Unfortunately, as you can see from [the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fba290c061027c24e4c8effdba37addd3430c3d4/ext/curl/interface.c#L2311), the option value gets cast to a string before it's passed to the underlying library.

#### Solution

I've written a [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/531) that addresses the issue and allows for `NULL` to be passed for the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option value.

The above patch will take some time to get merged into the project, so until then you would have to explicitly set the method yourself once you start using this option.

#### Update

The fix has been applied to 5.5.11 and 5.6.0 (beta1).

Comment: +1 for checking the source, opening a bug and even creating a pull request to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Scytale You're welcome. Actually, I've also merged that PR myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Set CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to NULL and CURLOPT_HTTPGET to TRUE to reset back to an ordinary GET.

Answer (score 0):

*(Shrug ...)* And what I wound up doing in my API is to simply, "set it every time."  My `POST` routine simply sets a custom-header of `"POST"`, and so on. Works great.

I found that, once you do set a custom-header, it "sticks."  Future calls which then attempt to do ordinary `GET, POST, PUT` start to fail.  I experimented with the suggestions listed earlier in this post *(with PHP-7),* and didn't very-quickly meet with success ... so: "to heck with it, this isn't elegant, but it works."