# remove previos CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST in php

Tags: php, libcurl

In my code I have

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,$custom_request);
```

and it works OK, but below in the program I want to do normal requests without thus custom request. The curl manual says the default value is null but I tried in **php** and it does not work.

I'm using php-5.4.31

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset CURLOPT\_CUSTOMREQUEST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163865/how-to-reset-curlopt-customrequest)

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. I've found the answer in other post:

[How to reset CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163865/how-to-reset-curlopt-customrequest)

The response is: it works in php 5.5.11

Comment: So you have created answer which is already exists. Probably you should delete your?