# Webdav API and Curl PHP - COPY Method

Tags: php, curl, webdav

Hi I been digging the web for an answer...
I have read lot's of documentation but couldn't make it work.
Why can't I COPY / paste a remote folder inside the same remote server.

This works fine:

curl -k -u user:pass -X COPY -h 'Destination: https://server.lc/remote.php/webdav/USER/DESTINATION' https://server.lc/remote.php/webdav/USER/folder

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$copt = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL             => "https://server.lc/remote.php/webdav/USER/folder",
    CURLOPT_USERPWD         => "user:pass",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "COPY",
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Destination: ' . "https://server.lc/remote.php/webdav/USER/$folder"),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
];

curl_setopt_array($ch, $copt);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I can't see any debug info, if you have any ideias please share.

Comment: Since no info about the error message read more  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163865/how-to-reset-curlopt-customrequest

Comment: I've made a few moves in order to debug the curl request but nothing comes back and I've used CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1

Comment: First of all let us know the what the error is like, is that 500 error or what, and you can change [] to array() because on PHP < 5.4 it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your input I really have no ideia about the error... this is stupid but I'm working on a production client app and can't (for now) go in debug mode... I'll see what I can do perhaps setting up a temporary apache website...

Comment: This code is working at the developing domain... not sure what's happening so I apologize for any inconveniente. I hope that somebody take something out of this. at least you have an example on how to implement COPY ;)